# Como comparar duas colunas de uma planilha, e manter as informações que são iguais?

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Olá!

Eu estou trabalhando com uma planilha no Excel que possui essa estrutura:

```
Coluna_A    Coluna_B
A           A
B           B
C           C
C_1         E
D
E
F
```

O que eu quero é descobrir uma forma de montar uma terceira coluna, que possua dados presentes nas duas colunas. Assim:

```
Coluna_C
A
B
C
E
```

Notem que a unidade amostral "E" da "Coluna_B" está na mesma linha que "C_1", da "Coluna_A", mas ainda assim ela deve estar na "Coluna_C", pelo fato de se encontrar em ambas as colunas. Alguém saberia algum código para automatizar essa análise, seja no Excel, ou no R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez o seguinte seja o que quer.
Note que os elementos comuns às duas colunas são os primeiros elementos do vetor `Coluna_C`, seja qual for a sua posição nos vetores originais, `Coluna_A` ou `Coluna_B`.

```
dados$Coluna_C <- NA
comuns <- intersect(dados$Coluna_A, dados$Coluna_B)
dados$Coluna_C[seq_along(comuns)] <- comuns
dados
#  Coluna_A Coluna_B Coluna_C
#1        A        A        A
#2        B        B        B
#3        C        C        C
#4      C_1        E        E
#5        D              <NA>
#6        E              <NA>
#7        F              <NA>
```

Se não quiser valores `NA`, comece com

```
dados$Coluna_C <- ""
```

**Dados.**

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
Coluna_A    Coluna_B
A           A
B           B
C           C
C_1         E
D
E
F
", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```